# Verbose Mode is dropped on macOS Sierra?

Tags: command-line, macos

[image][image]

Hi guys,

Anyone know if Apple removed Verbose Mode in macOS Sierra or not? When It seems Verbose Mode couldn't be accessed any more.

One more thing, it also doesn't work with booting into Single-user Mode, Safe Mode or Verbose Mode via command line.

Any reply would be appreciated. Thanks.

Best Regards,
Vincent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

System Integrity Protection (SIP) disables changes to NVRAM. In order to make changes, you need to temporarily disable SIP by doing the following:

1. Boot into Recovery Mode. (Hold <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> from the time you start your machine until the Apple logo appears.)
2. Open the Terminal from the Utilities menu.
3. Enter the command:

   ```
   csrutil disable
   ```
4. Reboot and you will be able to run your desired commands from within a normal session.
5. It's *strongly* recommended that you re-enable SIP when you're done making adjustments. To do so, run this command:

   ```
   csrutil enable
   ```

Note that if you intend to make a lot of changes to NVRAM, you can leave SIP enabled but disable NVRAM protection by running the following command from the Recovery Mode Terminal:

```
csrutil enable --without nvram
```

Again, you will need to reboot for changes to be effective.

Comment: Hi @tubedogg, thanks for your promoting response. Really appreciated. But I don't think so. Even with SIP enabled in OS X El Capitan, I could boot t into Safe Mode or Single-user Mode with command line. Here is the screenshot for your reference.

Comment: Just because something worked in El Capitan doesn't mean it hasn't changed in Sierra. And NVRAM modification shouldn't have worked in El Capitan, either. In any event, did you test disabling SIP, or at least disabling NVRAM protection? That's a sure way to find out.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. Disabling SIP or NVRAM protection works well for command line. I take my words back. Thank you very much. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2):

As best I can tell in Sierra, it is still possible to:
 `sudo nvram boot-args="-v"`
without disabling SIP.

However, the interesting thing is that while Vervose mode works at boot as it always has, it no longer displays anything at shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this page while looking for something related. In my case I needed to be in Verbose mode in Mojave, and it seemed like neither command-s or command-v worked. But I did find an answer elsewhere to the problem.

As was said, using command-r and then Terminal from the Utilities menu will give you single user mode.

For Verbose mode, the significant change is when you have used FileVault, which was the case for my work machine. Instead of letting go of the keys at the Apple logo stage, you keep holding them until you get to the log in stage. Then sign in as usual, and after the log in screen goes away you see the usual thousands of lines scrolling by.