# Virtual Mac boots in verbose mode -- why?

Tags: startup, virtualization, virtualbox

Some time back, I used Parallels Desktop on a Mac running macOS Catalina (10.15) as a host system to create a virtual machine running OS X Sierra (10.13). Everything ran fine, if a bit slow.  Then I migrated my VM to VirtualBox, following [the instructions here.](https://www.neekey.net/2020/07/21/migrate-your-parallel-desktop-vm-to-virtualbox/)  Everything continues to work fine, with one very minor glitch:  whenever I start up the VM, it boots in verbose mode. (The original Parallels VM did not do this.)  Any idea why this is happening, or what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Note the name of your virtual machine. The example image below shows the virtual machine named "High Sierra Clone" is currently running.

[image]

Open a Terminal application window in the virtual machine and enter the command below.

```
nvram boot-args
```

Example output is given below.

```
usb=0x800 keepsyms=1 -v -serial=0x1
```

Open a Terminal application window on the host machine and enter the following command, where the `‑v` option has been omitted from `<value>`.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" VBoxInternal2/EfiBootArgs <value>
```

Below is an example.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "High Sierra Clone" VBoxInternal2/EfiBootArgs "usb=0x800 keepsyms=1 -serial=0x1"
```

On restart of the virtual machine, the verbose mode was gone. However the following output did appear.

[image]

---

Tested using an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) with macOS Catalina 10.15.7) as the host and macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 guest installed in VirtualBox 6.1.32.

### References

- [3.14.2. Specifying Boot Arguments (Oracle® VM VirtualBoxUser Manual for Release 6.0)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/efi.html#efibootargs)
- [Setting a NVRAM variable in normal boot not permitted but allowed in recovery mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315120/setting-a-nvram-variable-in-normal-boot-not-permitted-but-allowed-in-recovery-mo)
- [Is there a list of available boot-args for darwin / OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/255176/is-there-a-list-of-available-boot-args-for-darwin-os-x)
- [How do you start a debug mode in Virtualbox GUI tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372856/how-do-you-start-a-debug-mode-in-virtualbox-gui-tool)

Comment: I find it more interesting how you got High Sierra running on Virtualbox haha

Comment: @Lano: I do not believe I included an explanation of how I installed High Sierra as a VirtualBox guest. I used a different virtual machine to create a virtual bootable installer using the instructions from the Apple website ["How to create a bootable installer for macOS"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).